# Don't output markdown in Jekyll build, only HTML

Tags: jekyll

When I build my site using Jekyll, I get both the raw Markdown and the rendered HTML files in the `_site` output directory. How can I tell Jekyll to not output the `.md` files?

[image: Screenshot of Jekyll output directory]

PS.: It's not a breaking flaw, but it creates noise and the direct link to the `.md` files can be entered in the browser, which I also don't want.

#### Edit (as requested in the comments):

I build using `build exec jekyll serve` and host on Github Pages: https://github.com/junge-pfarre/junge-pfarre.github.io

These are the relevant parts of `_config.yml`:

```yaml
defaults:
  - scope:
      path: ""
    values:
      layout: "default"
  - scope:
      path: "assets/flyer"
    values:
      flyer: true

markdown: kramdown

permalink: :title
```

The markdown files don't have a frontmatter (e.g. `gebete.md`):

```
# Gebete

_Hier soll es in Zukunft von uns selbst geschriebene Gebete geben._
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add front matter to each markdown file and jekyll will process them generating the HTML version in _site directory, leaving original md files out.